# Establishing a 1 to 1 relationship between tables

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, constraint

I have a table `Nurse`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nurse](
    [EmployeeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WardId]     [int]               NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Nurse] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and a table `Employee`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [Id]            [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]          [nvarchar](100)     NOT NULL,
    [StaffNumber]   [nvarchar](50)      NOT NULL,
    [Salary]        [money]             NOT NULL,
    [Address]       [nvarchar](max)     NOT NULL,
    [GenderId]      [int]               NOT NULL,
    [ContactNumber] [nvarchar](20)      NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

How do I establish a 1:1 relationship between the two tables?

There is one nurse for one employee, only the `Nurse` table is separated from the `Employee` table as it has to be part of relationships, such as, just any employee, e.g. a `Nurse` belongs to a `Ward`, while a `Doctor`, also an employee, belongs to a `Department`.

Answer (score 11):

I guess that you mean: *"every `Nurse` **is** an `Employee`"*.

This can be done with (keeping the `Employee` table as it is):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,        -- why not name this EmployeeId ?
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [StaffNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Salary] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [GenderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ContactNumber] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ( [Id] )
 ) ;
```

and changing the `Nurse` table so the primary key is not an `IDENTITY` and it has a foreign key that references the `Employee (Id)`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nurse](
    [EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,                 -- not IDENTITY !
    [WardId] [int] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Nurse] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ( EmployeeId ),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Nurse] FOREIGN KEY  
    ( EmployeeId )
    REFERENCES dbo.Employee ( Id )
) ;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check this out later. I must revisit some very old code to do so. `Employee.Id` is named such because all my pure PKs are always named only `Id`. It is generally accepted, and also a very simple and useful convention for me, not to mention one recognised by EF conventions at the time of my OP. It cannot be ambiguous, neither in queries only involving the `Employee` table, nor in multi-table queries, where T-SQL syntax will require a qualifying table - or alias - prefix.

Comment: Thank you for saying to remove the identity value from Nurse! That is exactly the right way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems all you need to do is to add a primary key to your Nurse table and add a unique'  foreign key relationship from the Nurse table to the Employee table;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [StaffNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Salary] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [GenderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ContactNumber] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
))

GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nurse](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId] [int] FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(ID),
    [WardId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Nurse] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
))
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_NURSE_EMPLOYEEID ON dbo.Nurse ( EmployeeId )
```

Comment: But leaving that `Id` column in the `Nurse` table seems like a serious problem waiting to happen! There's absolutely no need for it in there. If you want to have an FK to a Nurse, you call it `NurseId` and put the FK to the `Nurse` table. Re-aliasing a surrogate key to an arbitrary second surrogate key is bound to cause problems. Think of how when that identity column is not present and you have a `NurseId`, you can join directly to the `Employee` table with it! Why force a join through `Nurse` with a needless layer of abstraction that had no benefits?

Comment: @ErikE Nobody has even mentioned needing an FK to `Nurse`. I rather had in mind an FK in `Nurse` that references `Employee`. Without the `Id` column, `Nurse` has no surrogate PK at all, so how could introducing `Id` imply a second surrogate PK? A single, purely surrogate, PK is in no way at all a "needless layer of abstraction".

Comment: @ProfK Somebody did too mention needing an FK to `Nurse`: I did. I think you're not understanding what I'm saying. The entity in question, the `Nurse`, is a "subclass" of  `Employee` and thus already has a surrogate PK, the identity value from `Employee`. Adding another one gives each `Nurse` two synthetic keys: `Employee.Id` and `Nurse.Id`. This is a completely needless, and probably harmful, extra key. If this were a C# class `public class Nurse : Employee { }`, how would you expose the Nurse `Id`, and why would you need to since it already has Id` by virtue of being a subclass of Employee?

Comment: The relationship between `Employee` and `Nurse` is "1 to 0-or-1". Such relationships require no `Id int identity(1,1)` column in the second table. Doing so is just a habit on the part of people who aren't thinking clearly about what the larger relation is between the two tables (after they have been joined).

Comment: @ErikE Granted, the `Id` on `Nurse` is not necessary, but I disagree about it being harmful. Creating a database structure focused on being used by inheritance in a ORM is, in my opinion, not necessarily harmful, but a very bad DB design pattern.

Comment: @ProfK Who said anything about ORMs? The extra Id is harmful because 1. It will eventually hurt performance by forcing an extra, unneeded join somewhere, 2. It will prevent an FK from being created, and 3. It can make it very difficult to copy data from one set of rows as a template to another. I have personally seen all three of these in a database and regretted the double artificial key a lot. You may think differently, but if you agree it's not *necessary*, then you should  agree it's bad to add unnecessary data.

Comment: Touche, @ErikE. I suppose it's a balance of my conventions, and circumstances of that project, and I may have given the former more weight than necessary over the latter.